# Prove that permeance is inversely proportional to reluctance

Tags: electromagnetism

"I took an exam on Sunday, which had this question:

> "Reluctance ($\Re$) is the opposition of the medium to the establishment and
> concentration of magnetic field lines. Which variable impacts this
> quantity inversely?
> (A) Magnetomotive force
> (B) Cross-sectional area
> (C) Length  (D) Permeance  (E) Electric current."

The answer provided by the board was option (B)Cross-sectional area, which I believe is correct as well. However, I also think that permeance (P) would be a correct answer because (D) permeance is the inverse of reluctance, and both are reciprocal.

We still have to:

$\Re=\frac{1}{P}$

$\Re=\frac{l}{\mu_{0}\mu_{r}A}$, $\Re$ is the reluctance in amepere-turns per weber, $l$ is the length of the circuit in metrers, $\mu_{0}$ is the permeability of vacuum in H/m, $\mu_{r}$ is the relative magnetice permeatiblity of the material (dimensionless) and A is the cross-sectional area of the circuit in square metres.

$P=\frac{\mu_{0}\mu_{r}A}{l}$

So, I need to prove that permeance is also a correct answer to the test organizer and try to request a review for this question, but I don't know how I can prove it, as clearly both are inversely proportional, as evidenced by the formulas. And if I rely solely on this, they probably won't accept my review.

Answer (score 0):

I mean the definition of Permeance is $P=\frac{1}{R}$. So, permeance will not, like, affect the reluctance, since it is defined by reluctance. I think you could say that this question is not rigorously designed.